# SImon cipher in CBC mode using Python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, cbc-mode

I want to implement CBC mode in Simon Cipher and i also have put the initialization vector. My problem is why the decryption output give the wrong result. The output shows that the encrypted message and decrypted message give almost same result.

> ciphertext (hex):  0x318e8458049de850c85afb1e05d737b1

> Plaintext (hex) :  0x318e8458049de850c85afb1e05d7339b

This is [my code](https://github.com/windaezranata/TA.git). Is there any recommended solution for my problem?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you implement Simon in ECB mode and successfully decrypt it? Once you have that working correctly, then you can try implementing CBC mode. Yes, I am aware the ECB is insecure, but other modes, including CBC, are built on top of it. If ECB doesn't work then the other modes will also fail.

Comment: @rossum My code can run successfully in ECB mode, it can encrypt and decrypt, and give the correct output. But if i use the CBC mode, it doesn't give the same result as plaintext that i use in the code

Comment: Then your error is probably in the CBC part of the code. Check both the encryption and decryption CBC specific sections very thoroughly. One trick is to use a zero IV: 0000...000 and compare the encrypted first block with the ECB encrypted first block. They should be identical.

Comment: Don't you need to call `decrypt(b, a)` instead of `decrypt(a, b)`? Note that your CBC code is only for single block encrypt as it currently stands. If you have tested the block cipher itself you should probably include the CBC-relevant code and point to the Simon cipher in github. Just putting all the code in github and pointing it out makes your question off topic.

Comment: @rossum I've tried your advice, and i found that the trouble is in the decryption process, because when i tried ECB and CBC with IV 000...000 had same result in encryption process. But i still confused which part in decryption process that makes the decryption output still wrong